# Let array_agg() return no rows when there are no input rows

Tags: postgresql

When there are no rows, the function `array_agg()` returns `null`. How can I alter this so that no rows are returned? For example, take the following simple query:

```
select array_agg(country)
from   country
where  false
```

This returns one row with value `null`. I would like to have no rows returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause to remove empty arrays:

```
[local] #= select array_agg(1) from a where false;
┌───────────┐
│ array_agg │
├───────────┤
│ (null)    │
└───────────┘
(1 row)

[local] #= select array_agg(1) from a where false having array_agg(1) <> '{}';
┌───────────┐
│ array_agg │
├───────────┤
└───────────┘
(0 rows)
```